# Trouble Creating Stored Procedure Insert Statement in .NET with VisualStudio/TableAdapter

Tags: sql, .net, visual-studio, sql-insert, tableadapter

I am trying to create a `TableAdapter` for a typed DataSet for my persistence layer. I am going to read information from a file, and then insert that into the database.

- The information in the file is a SerialNumber, VOCLevel, Date, Time, Accuracy.
- The information I need to insert is MonitorID, VOCLevel, Date, Time, Accuracy.

The `SerialNumber` is related to a `MonitorID` in the database. The insert I am trying to write in the `TableAdapter` Config Wizard in Visual Studio is:

```
INSERT INTO VOCReading (MonitorID, Level, Date, Time, Accuracy)
VALUES( (SELECT MonitorID FROM Monitor WHERE SerialNumber= @SerialNumber), @Level, @Date, @Time, @Accuracy)
```

The error I get is

> Must declare the scalar variable '@SerialNumber'

How can I get around this? `SerialNumber` is in the `Monitor` table, but the table I need to insert into is `VOCReading`.

Comment: Have you `@SerialNumber` in you command parameter list? Also, your insert query is wrong.

Comment: Yah, I accidently typed SensorName a few times instead of SerialNumber a couple times, but that's been fixed.  SerialNumber is not a column in the table I am trying to insert into. The SerialNumber is from an Arduino. However, each SerialNumber maps directly to a MonitorID, which is the Primary Key to the Monitor Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT` command comes in two flavors:

**(1)** either you have all your values available, as literals or SQL Server variables - in that case, you can use the `INSERT .. VALUES()` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES(Value1, Value2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., ValueN)
```

Note: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of column to insert data into - that way, you won't have any nasty surprises if suddenly your table has an extra column, or if your tables has an `IDENTITY` or computed column. Yes - it's a tiny bit more work - **once** - but then you have your `INSERT` statement as solid as it can be and you won't have to constantly fiddle around with it if your table changes.

**(2)** if you **don't** have all your values as literals and/or variables, but instead you want to rely on another table, multiple tables, or views, to provide the values, then you can use the `INSERT ... SELECT ...` approach:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT
       SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, @Variable3, @Variable4, ...., SourceColumnN
   FROM
       dbo.YourProvidingTableOrView
```

Here, you must define exactly as many items in the `SELECT` as your `INSERT` expects - and those can be columns from the table(s) (or view(s)), or those can be literals or variables. Again: explicitly provide the list of columns to insert into - see above.

You can use **one or the other** - but you **cannot** mix the two - you cannot use `VALUES(...)` and then have a `SELECT` query in the middle of your list of values - pick one of the two - stick with it.

So in your case, you'd have to use the `INSERT .. SELECT` approach since you need to select something from a table - you cannot use the `VALUES` approach:

```
INSERT INTO VOCReading (MonitorID, Level, Date, Time, Accuracy)
    SELECT MonitorID, @Level, @Date, @Time, @Accuracy
    FROM Monitor 
    WHERE SerialNumber = @SerialNumber
```

Comment: You my friend, are awesome!